# Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\arctan(\frac{1}{k}))^{2}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I'm trying to figure out whether the following series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\arctan(\frac{1}{k}))^{2}$$

My first thought was to compare $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\arctan(\frac{1}{k}))^{2}$ with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\arctan(\frac{1}{k})$ and see if the later converges, which would implicate that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\arctan(\frac{1}{k}))^{2}$ converges. This because $(\arctan(\frac{1}{k}))^{2}\leq\arctan(\frac{1}{k})$ for $k\geq1$. That was not the case.

I've also tried the quotient test and the root test but didn't see any success.

Can I just use that $\arctan(\frac{1}{k})\approx\frac{1}{k}$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ and then prove that it converges by proving that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k})^{2}$ converges? Is that valid? I guess it is, because we really just care about what happens at infinity, right?

Comment: hint: $|\tan^{-1} x| \le |x|$

Comment: The last lines are ok, you're using the comparison test

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can compare $\left(\arctan^2\left(\frac1k\right)\right)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ with $\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)_{k\in\Bbb N}$. And you can do it using the fact that\begin{align}\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\arctan^2\left(\frac1k\right)}{\frac1{k^2}}&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{\arctan\left(\frac1k\right)}{\frac1k}\right)^2\\&=\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac1k\right)}{\frac1k}\right)^2\\&=1.\end{align}So, by the comparison test, and since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}$ converges and both series are series of numbers greater than $0$, the series$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\arctan^2\left(\frac1k\right)$$converges.

Comment: Now if we could find an alternate or closed form.